# Getting Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json during docker build using Gitlab ci

Tags: asp.net, docker, asp.net-core, gitlab-ci

I am trying to run the Gitlab ci pipeline and i am getting the below issue when trying to build the docker image . I have added the corporate proxy certificate and as well as nuget certificate. Still unable to resolve it. I need help in resolving this.

'''

> #19 2.958 /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.415/NuGet.targets(128,5): error : Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json. [/src/tt.csproj]

> 85#19 2.958 /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.415/NuGet.targets(128,5): error : The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. [/src/tt.csproj]

> 86#19 2.958 /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.415/NuGet.targets(128,5): error : The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure. [/src/tt.csproj]
> '''

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-focal AS build
COPY ./CIdependencies/zscaler-rootca.cer /etc/ssl/certs/zscaler-rootca.cer
COPY ./CIdependencies/zscaler-nuget.cer /etc/ssl/certs/zscaler-nuget.cer
WORKDIR /etc/ssl/certs
RUN openssl x509 -inform DER -in zscaler-nuget.cer -out zscaler-nuget.crt
RUN openssl x509 -inform PEM -in zscaler-rootca.cer -out zscaler-rootca.crt
RUN update-ca-certificates
RUN echo $PWD
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["apps.csproj", ""]
RUN dotnet restore "./apps.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "apps.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build
RUN dotnet publish "apps.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish
```

Comment: It sounds like you haven't configured client certificates and/or proxy settings appropriately. How exactly did you 'add' the certificates? Could you also describe your network/proxy configuration?

Comment: @sytech i have added the first layer of dockerfile which we build for dotnet application.

Comment: My issue got resolved when i added the nuget and proxy certificate to the /etc/ssl/certs as mentioned in the above dockerfile and run the GitlabCI pipeline.